# Pass the value of html input text to Javascript Function and get the result

Tags: javascript, html

This is my very first time I'm using Javascript.
I have this Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function baunilha()
{
  var qb=document.getElementById("quantbaunilha").innerHTML;
  var prbau=5.58;
  var totbau=qtd*prbau;

}
  document.getElementById("valorlinhab").innerHTML=baunilha();

</script>
```

And, this is how the Function is called:

```
<tr>
<td><img src="/imagens/DOB_Baunilha.PNG" style="vertical-align: middle" alt="Ima_Bau">          </td>
<td>Caixa de 42 Unidoses de Detergente Ultra-Concentrado aroma Baunilha</td>
<td><input id="quantbaunilha" name="quantbaunilha" value="0" maxlength="2" type="text"    size="2" onchange="baunilha()"></td>
<td><input id="valorunib" name="valorunib" size="6" value="5.58">€</td>
<td><input id="valorlinhab" name="valorlinhab" size="8" value="0.00">€</td>
</tr>
```

So, I want that the result of the Function apears in text-box id="valorlinhab".
I tried the examples of w3schools, but they didn't work, as others examples in the web.
Is there someone who could help me? Any help is wellcome.
Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Watch out! www.w3fools.com ;)

Comment: To clarify Kvothe's comment a bit, w3schools is generally considered a very poor reference by professionals and is best avoided at all costs. They have a lot of factually incorrect and/or outdated information.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I really saw that for a severl times, such as, working with dtabases, and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be using value instead of innerHTML.  Additionally, you are using "qtb" instead of "qb" in your calculation.  You should also set the value inside the baunilha function.  Finally, you must tie an event listener to the input so that it will call the javascript function.

I also added a line which would check if the input is actually a number.

```
function baunilha()
{
    var qb=document.getElementById("quantbaunilha").value;

    //check that quantbaunilha is a number
    if(isNaN(parseFloat(qb)))
    {
        alert('Enter a number');
        return;
    }

    var prbau=5.58;

    document.getElementById("valorlinhab").value=qb*prbau;
}

document.getElementById("quantbaunilha").addEventListener('change', baunilha);
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uLfcG/3/

Comment: Well, it works in your code. But, if you please, check the corrected code that I have here: http://www.limpec.com.pt/duvida_javascript.txt and try it here: http://www.limpec.com.pt/comprar_dob.php. It's not working with me.

Comment: Replace the line "var totbau=qb*prbau;" in the baunhila function with "document.getElementById("valorlinhab").value=qb*prbau;"
Also, you need "()" after the word baunhila onchange in your input button to call the function.

Comment: Thank you Jem.I tried with your code, and still doesn't work in my webpage. I don't understand why. I'm really desapointed.

Comment: You need () after "baunhila" within your input onchange method

Comment: Lastly, I noticed your script is in the head.. Move the javascript to the end of the html body (before the closing tag) to add the event listener correctly.

Comment: Ok Jem. Now, it works. Thank you very much. I do appreciate your help. Some minor errors were doing great demages.

Comment: One last comment: Your page is still getting an error at addEventListener.  Looks like it will still work, but you may want to put your script within a "window.onload" javascript function or move it to the end of your html body code.

Answer (score 0):

You use `innerHTML` to put the results in to an element's inner HTML for a tag with both an opening and closing tag (like `<p>`).

Also, since you are using it for your `onchange` event, you should move the value setting in to the function as well.

For `<input>`, you set the value attribute instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function baunilha() {
    var qb=document.getElementById("quantbaunilha").value;
    var prbau=5.58;
    var totbau=qb*prbau;

    document.getElementById("valorlinhab").value=totbau;
}    
</script>
```

That should do the trick.

Here is a JSFiddle with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/U7ZZh/

Also, you had a small typo on the line that is `var totbau=qtb*prbau` should be `var totbau=qb*prbau`

Comment: Oh, you also had one small typo on the totbau line. I made a note of it in my answer.